# WebSphere not scanning @webservice annotation

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I have this web application (Ear) which contains jax-ws web services using `@webservice` annotation. 
It runs fine on local server which is WebSphere. But the same app when deployed in dev server is not running i.e. not scanning the code for `@webservice` annotation. There are no wsdl files present in the Ear. Only annotation based web services are present.
WebSphere version is 8.5.5.11.
Application is set at j2ee 1.5 via web.xml 
There is spring context loader listener added and dispatcher servlet configured for '/' path in web.xml.
I tried deploying the same Ear in another server and there it was working fine.
Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to deployment. When WAS admin console is used to deploy, i was not adding / to the context root. This seems to be causing the issue. Not sure why!

Comment: Two apps mapped to the same context root "/" might keep the second one from coming up, but that should be logged. If the logs don't show anything else going amiss during deploy/start, there's a property "disableIBMJaxwsengine" that could cause what you're seeing, but that would stop all jax-ws apps on the server.

Answer (score 0):

jee5 versions of web.xml need a JVM property to be set in order for them to be scanned.  From the Knowledgecenter:

com.ibm.websphere.webservices.UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy

Use this property to control whether the product scans WAR 2.4 and earlier modules for JAXWS components and semi-managed service clients. By default, these legacy WAR modules are only scans for semi-managed service clients.

If you set this, next 
you'll need to bounce WebSphere, then 
uninstall and reinstall the app for the jax-ws services to be detected.

Comment: com.ibm.websphere.webservices.UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy=true

Comment: This is for war 2.4 modules. But my application is at version 2.5